# How would I go about using getters and setters for an ArrayList in Java? Here is what I have. This code is not working. what is the reason?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, getter-setter

I need to set some items into the array via setters and also I need to get those details by using getters to another. Problem is it is gives me a Null. What is the problem here? Can some one help me?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class arrayClass {
private ArrayList<String> sampleArrays;
    
public ArrayList<String> getSampleArrays() {
return sampleArrays;
}
    
public void setSampleArrays(ArrayList<String> sampleArrays) {
this.sampleArrays = sampleArrays;
}       
}
```

Second Class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FirstPage {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        arrayClass ac = new arrayClass();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("First");
        arrayList.add("Second");
        arrayList.add("Thired");
        arrayList.add("Fourth");
        ac.setSampleArrays(arrayList);

        Second second = new Second();
        second.testMeth();

    }

}
```

Third Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Second {

    public void testMeth() {
        
        arrayClass ar = new arrayClass();
        ArrayList<String> secondArray = ar.getSampleArrays();   
        System.out.println(secondArray.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: *import java.lang.reflect.Array;* - wot?

Answer (score 1):

In `main` your `arrayClass ac = new arrayClass();` is limited in scope to this method.  It is not a field.  In `testMeth` `arrayClass ar = new arrayClass();` is also a local variable, not a field.  They are not at all related to each other.

Furthermore, just because you declare a variable in one class, does not mean that another completely different class will be able to see it.

```
FirstPage::arrayClass
```

is not automatically accessible as

```
Second::arrayClass
```

To fix

You could create a constrcutor `Second second = new Second(ar);` and set this value to the field in `Second`

Answer (score 0):

[A valid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577929/19449899) has been shown by [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat). Another way you can get around this is to make `testMeth` take an `ArrayList<String>` as a parameter:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Second {

    public void testMeth(ArrayList<String> array) {
        ArrayList<String> secondArray = array;   
        System.out.println(secondArray.get(0));
    }

}
```

Accordingly, the main function should become:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    arrayClass ac = new arrayClass();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("First");
    arrayList.add("Second");
    arrayList.add("Thired");
    arrayList.add("Fourth");
    ac.setSampleArrays(arrayList);
 
    Second second = new Second();
    second.testMeth(ac.getSampleArrays());
}
```